# AngularJS Select Box with 2000 options slow in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that 2000 options in a select box is going to bring along some performance issues, but it works fine on Chrome and Firefox and Safari.

Basically, I am calling a web service which populates a select box. This is fairly quick and performance is fine on initial load. The issue is when I change routes, and then come back to the page with the select box on it. It takes ~40 seconds to load the view on IE. Is there anyway way to improve performance?

This is how it is set up:

```
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="model.searchParams.shipto" ng-options="ship.cd as ship.cd + (ship.cd===''?'' : ' - ') + ship.ds for ship in shiptoSelect" class="dropdownbar"></select>
```

This is the call that is made to retrieve the results. This is only executed once, and then the results are stored in my globalParams. So when I return to this view, this is not executed and the results are loaded from my globalParams service. That is when I run into performance issues.

```
    $scope.getShipTo = function() {
            $scope.model.searchParams.shipto = '';
            $scope.model.showProgress = true;
            MagicAPI.getShipToResults($scope.model.searchParams.brand, $scope.model.searchParams.soldto).then(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    var resSHIPAR = eval(response.data);
                    var resSHIPStr = resSHIPAR;

                    if (resSHIPStr.length * 1 === 0) {
                        globalParams.getAlertList().push({
                            type: 'info',
                            msg: 'No ship-to\'s exist for this account.'
                        });
                        $scope.model.showProgress = false;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        var selectObj = {
                            cd: '',
                            ds: '-- select --'
                        };
                        resSHIPStr.splice(0, 0, selectObj);
                        globalParams.setShipToList(resSHIPStr);
                        $scope.shiptoSelect = resSHIPStr;
                        $scope.model.showProgress = false;

                        for (var i = 0; i < resSHIPStr.length; i++) {
                            if(resSHIPStr[i].cd === $scope.model.searchParams.soldto) {
                                $scope.isSoldToMatch = true;
                                return;
                            } else {
                                $scope.isSoldToMatch = false;
                            }
                        } 
                        if ($scope.isSoldToMatch === false) {
                            globalParams.getAlertList().push({
                                type: 'info',
                                msg: 'No ship-to\'s exist for this account.'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, function(response) {
                $log.debug(response);
            });
        };
```

Comment: Try not to use ngOptions to render selectbox, go with custom directive that would not create bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read about `track by` and implement it

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

then your select becomes

```
<select name="" id="" 
  ng-model="model.searchParams.shipto" 
  ng-options="ship.cd as ship.cd + (ship.cd===''?'' : ' - ') + ship.ds for ship in shiptoSelect track by ship.id" class="dropdownbar"></select>
```